# How to show the toolbar layout only when a song is played (ListView item is clicked)

Tags: android, listview, android-toolbar

activity_main2.xml

I want to show the toolbar in the following code only when a listView item is clicked. Otherwise, remain hidden. If I use (View.Invisible) in the Java Code then the layout disappears, yet white space remains in its area. I want the listview to occupy that area.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ashutosh.music_player.Main2Activity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/catv" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/track_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:overScrollHeader="@drawable/catv1"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/bar_player"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dark.DarkActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selected_track_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_track_title"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player_control"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try this .... setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: what is your actual need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,This is what @shijil Said

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ashutosh.music_player.Main2Activity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/catv" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/track_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:overScrollHeader="@drawable/catv1"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/bar_player"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dark.DarkActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selected_track_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selected_track_title"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player_control"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</LinearLayout>
```

and set programatically

```
.setVisibility(View.GONE);
.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

as needed

Comment: Hell Yeah, this works exactly the way I want . No issues with reappearing of toolbar too. Thanks Gibin.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Relative Layout to do so. In this way, if you set the toolbar as invisible, the list view will occupy its position.

Comment: try what shijil said it can also meety your need

Comment: Why that wont work? Also how will it work in relative layout with invisible toolbar

Comment: Should I enclose Listview and toolbar in a FrameLayout, as when clicking on the song, song is played but toolbar doesn't appear. I have set the visibilty to view onClick.

Comment: As far as I remember, by default all items in relative layout aren't arranged. They overlap each other if relation if not provided. So if there isn't any Toolbar, ListView will adjust itself.

Comment: Try enclosing them in Relative Layout while keeping the parent layout as Linear.

Comment: @BasuNoname Try before you say something "It may not work. Cause, he's using LinearLayout " only in linear layout he could do that without complex work